# The initialized data which is not in data section gets initialized in STM32 and it shouldn't

Tags: c, stm32, linker-scripts

I'm programming STM32L432KC and I want to put it in standby mode which preserves `SRAM2` content. To do that I created a separated section in memory by separating the `SRAM1` from `SRAM2`.

In this chip, the `SRAM1` and the `SRAM2` can be treated as a continuous memory region, so originally the memory was mapped like that in the linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 256K
}
```

I changed it to separate the `SRAM1` and `SRAM2`:

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 48K
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 256K
SRAM2 (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

The region `0x2000C000 - 0x20010000` is mapped to `0x10000000 - 0x10004000` by default.

Then I mapped a section to the new memory region in the linker script:

```
  .sram2 :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ssram2 = .;
    *(.sram2)
    *(.sram2*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _esram2 = .;
  } > SRAM2
```

And then put an initialized global variable in the new section:

```
static unsigned test_var __attribute__((section(".sram2")) = 10;
```

The problem is that I didn't edit the startup code to copy the initialized data into the `SRAM2`, but when I debug I can see that the variable gets initialized and I think it shouldn't.

The question is: why it is initialized?

I wonder if STLinkV2 apart from flashing the device it also initializes the RAM region.

Comment: It's either the startup code which can handle the copying of initialized data to their run-time location. *Or* the linker places the the data in the correct sections at the correct addresses, so the program loaded does it.

Comment: You need to check the startup code. Non L4 ones only initialize the one .data section. Post the startup code here otherwise I cant help. Place the breakpoint at the ResetHandler and see what is happening.

Comment: You probably will need to let linker to save the data into the flash `} >SRAM2 AT> FLASH` and add couple of C or asm lines in the startup. I usually call the C routine from the ASM startup for it (I am avoiding assembler, when I was younger I had to write a lots in it and have enough)

Comment: @P__J__ the startup code is automatically generated with Cube and it's the same like [here](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/system/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32l432xx.s).
Will that `} >SRAM2 AT> FLASH` treat uninitialized data as it was initialized? I mean I would like to preserve the same functionality of `bss` and `data` in the `SRAM2` as it works in "normal" RAM.

Comment: Yes you need to have the same for all separate data and bss segments

Comment: When use CCM RAM I do the same

Comment: @P__J__ Ok, then I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314424/multiple-bss-and-data-segments)